# Gtkmm - Hiding a window without closing the application

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

How do i hide a toplevel window without closing it?

NdmWindow is a class inherited from Gtk::Window.
I have added the instance of NdmWindow to Gtk::Application.

Now, how do i hide it instead of closing it?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window->`[`hide`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a285c1775842292ae4bc6d074aa892c61)`();`

Don't forget to look at classes that `Gtk::Window` inherits from.

**EDIT**

I don't know, but my suggestion is to try `hold()`, and then `release()` after you show the next window.

Comment: The only two functions i could find are hide() and set_visible(). Both inherited from Gtk::Widget and both quits the application.

Comment: That's why you should never fail to report what you have tried already ;-) Your question says: _How do I hide a window without closing it?_ If you don't say that you are aware of `hide()` and have tried it already, then people will assume that you need `hide()` and you just didn't read the documentation. I don't know the answer to your real question, but I have a guess - see edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Hold and release are the ones i'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-January/msg07191.html), the behavior is that when a window is hidden, it is removed from `Gtk::Application`, and so if it is the last window, the app quits.

If you want your application to keep running when no windows are showing, the solution is to call `hold()` on your `Gtk::Application` object to increase the reference count of the application.  Presumably you do this before setting up any windows, and call the corresponding `release()` as part of your quitting logic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works and doesn't `segfault`.
Save a reference to `Gtk::Application`, say send it as a param to your main `Window class` and call this `var app`, you'll need it later, it's needed because in some cases `get_application()` will return `null`.

In the delete event handler of your window call

```
app->hold();
hide();
return true;
```

Don't call `app->release()` when you want to make your window show up again since it will make your application exit completely. Just call `set_visible()` on your window object and it will show up.